# XML formatting a ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating a screen with the following (stacked on the page in this order):

[1] Header - with "Song Name"

[2] two buttons, side by side - "Back" and "Save"

[3] a horizontal line as separator

[4] a `ScrollView` which contains a single `EditText`

The goal of this page is to open a txt file within the `TextView` inside the `ScrollView`.  This txt file can be lengthy thus the need for scrolling option.  Once user edits the txt file pressing 'Save' will close the file and update the file source.

Here is what I have which is not working as the ScrollView is locked to the top of the screen and the Header and two buttons are all overlapping each other;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Header Section: Save, Back, and Song Name -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <!-- Save Button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:onClick="saveChanges" />

        <!-- Back Button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/saveButton" />

        <!-- Song Name TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Song Name"
            android:layout_below="@id/saveButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Artistic Line -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewSongName"
        android:background="@drawable/artistic_horizontal_line" />

    <!-- Linear Layout containing the ScrollView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewSongName">

        <!-- ScrollView for Editing -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextSongContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Edit song here" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried rearranging but nothing seems to create the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much nesting for `ScrollView` - correct layout should be:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
       ...
    <RelativeLayout/>
    <ScrollView>
       ...
    <ScrollView/>
<ConstraintLayout/>
```

Here is the corrected xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:onClick="saveChanges" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:onClick="goBack"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/saveButton" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Song Name"
            android:layout_below="@id/saveButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/artisticLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/artistic_horizontal_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/artisticLine">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextSongContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Edit song here"
            android:gravity="top"/>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```